# winrt usercontrol got clipped on animation

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

adding usercontrol out of bounds of view and animating it with storyboard translate transform x from right corner gets the usercontrol view get clipped

here is xaml code for animation

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="gridstory">
        <DoubleAnimation
                  Storyboard.TargetName="gdd"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                  From="0" To="-200" />

    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="gridstory2">
        <DoubleAnimation
                  Storyboard.TargetName="gdd"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                  From="-200" To="0" />


    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

am adding the usercontrol like this
c2.Margin = new Thickness(1355, 0, 0, 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1355 in your margin means the control will be laid out in the bounds of a rectangle that has the left border 1355 logical pixels away from the left border of its parent. On most screens that means that the layout rectangle is almost empty if not negative size, so it will usually get clipped. The solution might be to leave the Margin set to 0 and set HorizontalAlignment to Right and animate from c2.ActualWidth to 0 instead of 0 to -200.

Also check this article for something that might help you:

[Animating edge-based UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj649428.aspx)